# Does anyone know why the ValueErrorException is not showing?

Tags: python, object, exception, valueerror

```
class ValueErrorException(Exception):
    pass

class BankAccount(object):

    def __init__(self, balance):
        self.balance = balance


    def balance(self):
        if self.balance<0:
            raise ValueErrorException("Illegal Balance")
        else:
            return self.balance
x = BankAccount(-10)

print(x.balance)
```

Should print the error, but it prints -10. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You defined a property `.balance` and a method `.balance()` for this `BankAccount` class. Because they have the same name, one will overwrite the other. Make sure they have separate names, for example:

```
class BankAccount(object):
    def __init__(self, balance):
        self._balance = balance

def balance(self):
    if self._balance<0:
        raise ValueErrorException("Illegal Balance")
    else:
        return self._balance
```

And then call your `.balance()` method (note the brackets):

```
>>> x = BankAccount(-10)
>>> print(x.balance())
```

which should raise the desired Exception.

Answer (score 0):

In **init** you assign the value -10 to self.balance, you never call the method balance(). What you probably want is to use property and setter. That way every time a value is assigned to balance, a check is performed:

```
class BankAccount(object):

    def __init__(self, balance):
        self.balance = balance

    @property
    def balance(self):
        return self._balance

    @balance.setter
    def balance(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Illegal Balance")
        self._balance = value
```

Also, ValueError is a built-in exception in python, you don't need your own Exception class.